# Expire a Session after Closing the Browser OR after 30 Minutes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

How can I expire a session in Rails after a user closes the **browser OR after 30 minutes?** Whichever comes first?

I have tried in `session_store.rb` setting `expire_after: nil || 30.minutes` but doesn't work.

Rails 3.2

Comment: Are you using devise gem ?

Comment: @sam no I am not

Comment: Okay then you can try my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the issue was with caching. I had to restrict caching on the login page to avoid a lag displaying the home page as if the user was logged in.

In the application_controller.rb I set the following:

```
before_filter :set_cache_headers
def set_cache_headers
      expires_now
end
```

And in session_store.rb I set the session store to

```
expire_after: 30.minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the application's session information in the initializer file **config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
  :key => '_my_session', 
  :expire_after => 30.minutes
```

If you are using then Devise has a timeoutable module that you can use.

In your User model you would include :timeoutable with your devise models and in the **devise.rb** initializer you would configure it comparable to:

```
  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
```

You have to add **expire_after** key with nil value to the options:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', expire_after: nil
```

After applying this change, the session will expire when user closes the browser. You can read more about cookies expiration [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age)

Comment: This will only expire the session after 30 minutes. I want it to also expire if the user closes the browser. ?

Comment: You have to add expire_after key with nil value to the options:

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', expire_after: nil

Comment: Hmm, yes I went through that wiki and other answers here in SO, but the key is I want the session to expire **after 30 minutes OR browser is closed**

Comment: @Pants by default if closing browser, session will be destroyed as long if you have not made custom session.

Comment: @7urkm3n My problem seemed to be with caching issues. Thanks for the help.